# Why does my call to DateTime.TryParseExact fail?

Tags: .net, datetime

Simple question:

I call:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("May 16 13:47:12 2012", "MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedStartDate)
```

and the result is *false*.

Why did I do wrong?

Comment: dodexahedron is correct, but here's how I investigated it... "teach a man to fish", etc: `var s = new DateTime(2012, 5, 16, 13, 47, 12).ToString("MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));` - then compare `s` to your string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The time you are passing in is 24-hour time (the hour component is 13).

You need to use HH instead of hh to get 24 hour time.

Here is a useful MSDN page on all the time format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx